# How to create column from an expression

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark

[The doc](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.Column) says:

```
# 2. Create from an expression
df.colName + 1
1 / df.colName
```

Can anyone explain the meaning and usage of the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means the arithmetic operation with the old Column creates a new Column object:

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame([[1], [2]], ['a'])
df.show()
+---+
|  a|
+---+
|  1|
|  2|
+---+

df.a
# Column<b'a'>
df.a + 1
# Column<b'(a + 1)'>
1 / df.a
# Column<b'(1 / a)'>
```

`df.a`, `df.a + 1` and `1 / df.a` are all *Column* objects, what you want to ask is probably how to attach the column to the data frame, for which, you can use `select`:

```
df.select('a', (df.a + 1).alias('b')).show()
+---+---+
|  a|  b|
+---+---+
|  1|  2|
|  2|  3|
+---+---+
```

Or `withColumn`:

```
df.withColumn('b', df.a + 1).show()
+---+---+
|  a|  b|
+---+---+
|  1|  2|
|  2|  3|
+---+---+
```